# $.ajaxSetup headers not being sent on a $.ajax call

Tags: ajax

I have an JWT authentication API on my backend.

On my frontend app, I did this to set the token for every request:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' +localStorage.getItem('token')
    },
...
```

Now, when I call this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/user",
        type: 'GET',
...
```

It won't work, token is not attached to the call correctly, but.. if I call this:

```
$.ajax({
    headers: {
        "Authorization": 'Bearer ' +localStorage.getItem('token')
    },
    url: "http://localhost:8000/api/auth/user",
    type: 'GET',
...
```

It runs perfectly.

Now, it also runs well if I declare on $ajaxSetup like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr) {
        // Set the header
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' +localStorage.getItem('token'));
    },
```

Can anybody tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Despite what a lot of people seem to be saying on other answers, `headers` isn't a valid key for `$.ajaxSetup()`. [Check out the w3schools page](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_ajaxsetup.asp) on the method for a complete list of possible parameters.